# unable to install R library in azure ml

Tags: r, azure, cran, adaboost, azure-machine-learning-service

I have been trying to install a machine learning package that I can use in my R script.

I have done placed the tarball of the installer inside a zip file and am doing

```
install.packages("src/packagename_2.0-3.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

from within the R script. However, the progress indicator just circles indefinitely, and it's not installed in environment.

How can I install this package?

`ada` is the package I'm trying to install and `ada_2.0-3.tar.gz` is the file I'm using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the tarball packages. If you are on windows you need to do the following:

Once you install a package (+ it's dependencies) it will download the packages in a directory

> C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\some directory
>   name\downloaded_packages

These will be in a zip format. These are the packages you need.

Or download the windows binaries from cran.

Next you need to put all the needed packages in one total zip-file and upload this to AzureML as a new dataset.

in AzureML load the data package connected to a r-script

```
install.packages("src/ada.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
library(ada, lib.loc=".", verbose=TRUE)
```

Be sure to check that all dependent packages are available in Azure. Rpart is available.

For a complete overview, look at this [msdn blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjguin/archive/2014/09/24/how-to-upload-an-r-package-to-azure-machine-learning.aspx) explaining it a bit better with some visuals.